# Matlab contour plot from contourc data

Tags: matlab, contour

How, in Matlab, can I generate a contour plot from **contour data** such as that generated from `countourc`?    `contour` uses, internally, `contourc` to convert elevation data to contour data; but it's not obvious from documentation how I might be able to simply provide the contour data directly.

Comment: It does not look like you can do it _simply_ as you put it. It seems that `contour` uses `contourc` to create the `ContourMatrix`, then parse it and display the lines, but there is no way to make the function `contour` accept the `ContourMatrix` as input. If you want to start with `contourc`, then you'll have to generate the contour plot yourself by parsing the contour matrix and plotting each contour line yourself. To parse the contour matrix read this: [`ContourMatrix`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.contour-properties.html#budgut_-ContourMatrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you have older version of MATLAB

```
[C,h] = contour(peaks(30),-8:2:8);
h1 = get(h,'children');
X = get(h1,'xdata');
Y = get(h1,'ydata');
hold on
plot(X{5},Y{5},'.r')
hold off
```

This is for 2014 and newer

```
[C,h] = contour(peaks(30),-8:2:8);
i = 1;
slev = 4;                           % draw specific level
hold on
while i < size(C,2)
    ncnt = C(2,i);                  % number of points for current contour
    if abs(C(1,i) - slev) < 0.01    % check if it's desired contour
        icnt = i+(1:ncnt);
        plot(C(1,icnt), C(2,icnt), '.r')
        break;
    end
    i = i + ncnt + 1;               % next contour
end
hold off
```

Comment: Yes.  I've already wrote something almost identical (post 2014).  But I would rather not have to replicate other features of `contour`, features like fill and text.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many contour lines and want to plot **all curves with same line properties**, you can use the following function:

```
function h = contourC(C, varargin)
i = 1;
D = [C.' zeros(size(C, 2), 1)];
while (i < size(C,2))
    lvlv = C(1, i);                 % level value
    ncnt = C(2, i);                 % number of points for current contour
    D(i:i+ncnt, 3) = lvlv;
    D(i, :) = NaN;
    i = i + ncnt + 1;               % next contour
end
h = plot3(D(:, 1), D(:, 2), D(:, 3), varargin{:});
end
```

Parsing `ContourMatrix` (`C`) is borrowed from shade's answer, but it performs 30 times faster for my data since it calls `plot`/`plot3` only once.
This function plots each curve on its actual level, however, you can omit `D(:, 3)` and call `plot` for a flat contour. Use this like:

```
C = contourc(data, ...);
h = contourC(C, '-k', 'linewidth', 1);
```